# How do I use emacs in IBM AIX6.1? (only emacsclient is available, not server)

Tags: emacs, aix

I have an AIX6.1 system, with emacs installed from the rpm package emacs-24.5-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm downloaded from [IBM](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/date.html).

However, this only installs emacsclient on the machine, and I could not figure how to start the server (daemon) on this machine, since only emacsclient is available:

```
rpm -ql emacs-24.5-1
...
/usr/bin/emacsclient
/usr/bin/etags
/usr/bin/gctags
/usr/lib/emacs
```

So any idea on how to use emacs on AIX?

Comment: RTFM.  `emacs` is the server.  You can automatically start a server with `emacsclient -a ''` (note the empty string, it is not optional).

Comment: Also, you may want to compile your own Emacs, 24.5 is getting pretty old (2015).  If you can install a toolchain and the build dependencies, it's not hard.

Answer (score 2):

The page you have linked to lists the following:

- `emacs-nox-24.5`  The Emacs text editor without support for the X Window System.
- `emacs-X11-24.5`  The Emacs text editor for the X Window System.
- `emacs-24.5`  The libraries needed to run the GNU Emacs text editor.

I believe you will need to install `emacs-24.5` *and* at least one of the other two.

i.e. the first two packages provide variants of the main Emacs executable, and the third provides everything else.